# How to pass a variable into a Kraken.js model?

Tags: node.js

I have a variable that holds my Sequelize connection, like so:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username');
```

With Kraken.js, how do I pass this into a module? I don't see where I could add this in the index.js configuration file...

Thanks!

(I can't tag this as krakenjs because I don't have enough karma.)

Comment: In other words, are you connecting your Kraken.js project models to your database through Sequelize?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to define my Kraken project models with Sequelize, but I'm not sure how because Sequelize requires a database connection to do so. Does that make sense?

Comment: Also, what type of database are you using?

Comment: I'm using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty similar setup to what's shown in this guide:

http://sequelizejs.com/articles/express

You would create the model file, (under `./models`). You'd need to register this model using the `associate` function (See previous link).

And to actually use the model, you could replicate the same usage as in the Kraken Shopping cart example https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Shopping_Cart/

eg: (After you've registered your models)

```
'use strict';
var Product = require('../models/productModel');

module.exports = function (server) {

 /**
* Display a list of the products.
*/
    server.get('/', function (req, res) {

        Product.find(function (err, prods) {

            res.render('index', products);    
        });   
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the connection in separate file and export it (http://openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/). I store such files in a dir called lib/

Then in the index.js (the starting point of the app) import the file using

```
require("./lib/..").
```

And then invoke it in index.js as

```
app.configure = function configure(nconf, next) {...};
```

(http://krakenjs.com/#structure_of_a_project)

A good sample app is https://github.com/lmarkus/Kraken_Example_Shopping_Cart